# Can I find the duration between the current time and the last time the file was open

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am using phonegap and I try to find the duration between the current time and the last time a file was open.

My first approach was to use the metadata but I was unable to find something else that the modificationTime, then parse it in order to get the date and then compare to the current date/hour.

My second approach was to write a timestamp in the file each time I open it and then compare it with the current timestamp.

Do you have a better approach to this problem ?

Comment: Have you tried using the **last modified** property of files? Every file has that.

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD Yes it's the first solution but then I split the string to get what I need and it's quite long

Comment: I believe the time can be converted to a timestamp, which you can use however you wish.

Comment: Thanks I will check in this direction